# Postmaster - Custom Field Notification

Tags: cartthrob, postmaster

Can't seem to pull a custom email variable from Cartthrob orders into the Postmaster. I can see postmaster is sending the message on authorisation but the variable is not showing the email address from the order field and shows the variable {order_custom_email}. What am I doing wrong? Can not I not use this custom variable in the order channel?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it to work.. changing the field to the supported variable shipping_region in the order channel fields and then updating the Postmaster Hook "To" field from {order_custom_email} to {hooks:shipping_region} sends the mail perfectly.